# Should I wait before updating to Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, updates

I'm not sure this is a question I should be asking here, but it is nonetheless important for me to know. I remember when Xcode 4 first came out there were still a considerable amount of bugs that were only ironed out after a few updates.

Now that Xcode 5 has come out, I find myself asking this question: "Is it safe to update from 4 to 5 and start developing on Xcode 5, or is Xcode 5 still buggy enough that it might corrupt my project files, or otherwise make me lose my work in some way?"

What has been your experience and what do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been using Xcode 5 for months without issues. It has many useful new features. So **yes**, move to Xcode 5.

BTW, I was not a fan of Xcode 4 when it came out and did not move to it for over a year.

Comment: Yes, I think some new features are awesome, so I'm eager to update. In fact, I'm going to do it right now :)

Answer (score 1):

I updated to Xcode 5 about three weeks ago, i was afraiding of many new bugs and issues but i did not have any problem with Xcode 5, it works better than i think. I recommend to you to update your Xcode.  I had three projects in Xcode 4 and i didn't get any error in Xcode 5, they all work.